# What does wpspectrum's output 'Spec' mean?

Tags: matlab, wavelet-transform

[image]

Used 'wpspectrum' to do wavelet packet transform, the function have 3 outputs:

> [time,freq,Spec].

But I don't know what the Spec mean?
Does it denote energy or wavelet coefficients?